# How to map ubercart attributes to CCK fields?

Tags: 7, views, entities, ubercart, nodes

The reason I am trying to map ubercart attributes to CCK fields because I can then use these CCK fields to display price list using views for many use cases.

Is there any fields references module which can do this?

Comment: I'd rather try to do it thru views (try Relationships) or add the necessary relationships via a custom module.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want fields and do not want to use your price in your views (though Ubercart is really compatible with views), you can use **Rules** to fill the value of a "hidden" *(I recommend you use [field permission](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) for that)* CCK numeric field.

Once you've created the field for your product content type, set the rule like this :

1. Event : **Content is created**
2. Condition : **Is of type** your product content type
3. Condition : **Entity has field** your numeric hidden field
4. Action : **Add a variable** : get your price value
5. Action : **Convert data type** : make it numeric
6. Action : **Set a data value** : set your hidden field value.

*(Maybe this 3 last actions can be done in only 1 with "set a data value", it's worth trying it)*

Comment: hi @Gregory Kapustin, 

Thanks a lot, sure I will try it out

Comment: Any news here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drupal 7, then you can use module [Ubercart Field attributes](http://drupal.org/project/uc_field_attribute).
As mentioned in the project page of the module,

> This module links Ubercart's attribute system to Drupal core's fields API and allows to automatically create product attributes from fields and options from the multi-values.

If you are using drupal 6, then there is module [Ubercart CCK Attribute](http://drupal.org/project/uc_attribute_cck).